# Unable to build Pact-net: pact_ffi.dll not found

Tags: pact, pact-net

I'm trying to find a running pact-net sample. I've cloned [the pact-net repo](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-net/tree/master) but it won't build, getting this error:

```
Error   MSB3030 Could not copy the file "C:\Users\57046\Source\repos\pact-net\build\windows\x86_64\pact_ffi.dll" because it was not found.  PactNet C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets    5150
```

There is [this closed issue](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-net/issues/377) which looks related but the workaround proposed there didn't work either: I've added the proposed win-x64 property to PactNet csproj file with no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should run scipt from pact-net repository `build/download-native-libs.sh` The script will install `pact_ffi.dll` to `windows\x86_64`. Or you can download `pact_ffi-windows-x86_64.dll.gz` manually from [pact-reference releases](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-reference/releases) and put pact_ffi.dll to `build\windows\x86_64`